# Gulp - cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

After running Gulp in cmd, I get the following error message :

```
 module.js:549
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pmp/gulpfile.js:14:14)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I have tried installing and uninstalling npm, it didn't work at all. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Install laravel-elixir

```
npm install laravel-elixir
```

Also did you run:

```
npm install
```

If not, run that too.

Comment: Thanks, it is still not working. I get the same error message when I run gulp in command.

Comment: Did you run npm install by itself